# Why does node Circle to Polygon module returns oval/ellipse instead of a shape like circle?

Tags: javascript, geojson, google-maps, circle, node-js

I'm using npm package circle-to-polygon and I wrote following code to return a polygon which is approximately like a circle.

```
const circleToPolygon = require('circle-to-polygon');

let coordinates = [28.612484207825005, 77.23574939044147]; //lat, lng

let radius = 311;      
let numberOfEdges = 32;    
let polygon = circleToPolygon(coordinates, radius, numberOfEdges);

let coords = polygon.coordinates;
```

When I used coords and created a polygon shape using Google Maps JS API, it showed a shape like oval (2 ends were very far from each other, two very near, hope you understand).

In fact, the different in distances one can say is roughly 4:1 ratio. So it's never a shape closer to circle.

Is there any issue, or is it supposed to do this intentionally?

See image. The circle you see is actual circle whose center and radius I used. The other shape is the oval I'm talking about. It's way too different.

[image]

Comment: If you plotted it on a globe, it would look like a circle, far north of Finland. If you want a less egg-shaped geodetic circle near New Delhi, reverse the coords to x,y order (lon,lat)

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix.

Comment: @Vince I tried reverse and in that case it showed same shape in sea somewhere in north west.

Comment: Please check the edit @Vince I've added the output image.

Comment: There are two sources of circular distortion, geodetic flexing due to the distances closer to the poles shrinking, and projection inaccuracy, as when using Web Mercator. You may have both at play. If you include the coordinates they can be reprojected into equal area and/or eqidistant projections, and you can check the circularity of the resulting geometry.

Comment: I didn't get the last line. Are you talking about solution? Could you please elaborate it a bit?

Comment: @Vikas Kumar hi, did u find a solution? I have the same problem :/

Comment: @Chiefir I quit programming.